# Get highest frequency terms from Lucene index

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, indexing, frequency

i need to extract **terms with highest frequencies from several lucene indexes**,  to use them for some semantic analysis.

So, I want to get maybe top 30  most occuring terms(still did not decide on threshold, i will analyze results) and their per-index counts. I am aware that I might lose some precision because of potentionally dropped duplicates, but for now, lets say i am ok with that.

So for the proposed solutions, (needless to say maybe) speed is not important, since I would do static analysis, I would put accent on **simplicity** of implementation because im not so skilled with Lucene and cant wrap my mind around some concepts of it..

I can not find any code samples from something similar, so all concrete advices (code, pseudocode, links to code samples...) Appreciate all the advices!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:
http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/02/summarization-with-lucene.html

The class in this page has`computeTopTermQuery` method which you should be easily able to retrofit for going over multiple indexes.

Comment: Hi mindas!
I using lucene 4.4 so it don't have terms() method ? help me, please!

Comment: @Thangnv you might want to open a separate thread for this, or email Lucene Java mailing list. I don't have Lucene 4.4 running on hand. And the time has been on short supply these days ;-(

Answer (score 5):

A very simple way would be to use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/). On the 'Overview' tab, there is a 'Show top terms' button that can be used for what you need.

Comment: That's the way. And you can copy-paste or even export the results.