# Fulltext Solr statistical search

Tags: lucene, solr

Consider I'm having a couple of documents indexed with Solr 4.0. Each has 2 fields - unique ID and text DATA field. DATA field contains few paragraphs of text. Who could advise me what kind of analyzers/parsers I should use and how to build statistical query to find out sorted list of most frequently used words in all DATA fields of all documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the most frequent terms look into the [terms-](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) and [statistical component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent)

Answer (score 1):

besides the answers mentioned here, you can use the "HighFreqTerms" class: its in the lucene-misc-4.0 jar (which is bundled with Solr).

This is a command line application which lets you see the top terms for any field either by document frequency or by total term frequency (the -t option)

Here is the usage:

```
java org.apache.lucene.misc.HighFreqTerms  [-t] [number_terms] [field]
   -t: include totalTermFreq
```

Here's the original patch, which is committed and in the 4.0 (trunk) and branch_3x codebases: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2393

Answer (score 0):

For ID field use analyzer based on **[keyword tokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory)** - it will take all the content of the field as a single token.

For DATA field use **[language specific analyzer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#English)**. Notice, that there's possibility to [auto-detect the language](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) of the text ([patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1979)).

I'm not sure, if it's possible to find the most frequent words with Solr, but if you can use Lucene itself, pay attention to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821903/get-highest-frequency-terms-from-lucene-index) question. My own suggestion for it is to use [HighFreqTerms](http://code.google.com/p/luke/source/browse/trunk/src/org/getopt/luke/HighFreqTerms.java?r=46) class from [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) project.