# Get most frequent words from Lucene 4.0 index

Tags: lucene

I'm quite new to Lucene. I have a Lucene 4.0 index and I would like to compute the nth most frequent words to create a stopword list. I found posts handling this in previous versions of Lucene such as [Get highest frequency terms from Lucene index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821903/get-highest-frequency-terms-from-lucene-index) however it seems reader.terms() has been deprecated in 4.0.

How could I achieve this using Lucene 4.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually Luke 4.0 does suit my purpose I realize. Anyways, a programmatic approach would be nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [New index statistics in Lucene 4.0 article](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/03/new-index-statistics-in-lucene-40.html) written by Mike McCandless, one of Lucene contributors. What you're looking for is probably `TermsEnum.totalTermFreq()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using `HighFreqTerms` from the lucene-misc package.

Note that you can user `HighFreqTerms.TotalTermFreqComparator` if you want to rank by term frequencies:

```
DocFreqComparator cmp = new HighFreqTerms.DocFreqComparator();
TermStats[] highFreqTerms = HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(reader, n, "text", cmp);

List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>(highFreqTerms.length);
for (TermStats ts : highFreqTerms) {
    terms.add(ts.termtext.utf8ToString());
}
```