# Finding hot topics in twits based on the frequency of the words

Tags: java, twitter, data-mining, text-mining

I am building a Java web service for finding the hot topics in a special location (latitude , longitude) based on the frequency of the word which is being used in the twits.

I am using twitter4j api for fetching the twits,and I can filter them with their location.
can anybody help me and tell me how to process the data and get the hot topics?

I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Is there no API in twitter that tells you the result already? Analyzing all the tweets in real-time will likely need a small server cluster. Apart from that have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821903/get-highest-frequency-terms-from-lucene-index or http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/04/hadoop-at-twitter.html

Comment: Thanks @zapl, I do have access to a server cluster.However, I could not find anything useful for my purpose,  or at least I have no idea how to process the stream to achieve my goal. I am wondering if you have any Idea for finding hot tweets based on number of retweets?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to look into "probabilistic latent semantic indexing". You can use the "topicmodels" package for that.

This video might be of use to you: [Video on Probabilistic latent semantic indexing](http://videolectures.net/mlss04_hofmann_irtm/)