# How to get top words by lucene index and search?

Tags: java, search, lucene, indexing

I used lucene library to create index and search. But now I want to get top 30 words are most of the words appearing in my texts. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Lucene 4.0 or later, you can use the [`HighFreqTerms`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/HighFreqTerms.html) class, such as:

```
TermStats[] commonTerms = HighFreqTerms.getHighFreqTerms(reader, 30, "mytextfield");
for (TermStats commonTerm : commonTerms) {
    System.out.println(commonTerm.termtext.utf8ToString()); //Or whatever you need to do with it
}
```

From each [`TermStats`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/TermStats.html) object, you can get the frequencies, field name, and text.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in SO got me this: [Get highest frequency terms from Lucene index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821903/get-highest-frequency-terms-from-lucene-index)

Would this work for you? sounded like the exact same question..